# Some Argument about conditional probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $x$ be a random variable, then what is the conditional probability density function $p(x|x)$? And if $e$ is another random variable, what is $p(x+e|x)$? Is $p(x+e|x)=p(e|x)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional on $X = x$, i.e. $X|X = x$ is just a degenerate random variable, with one support point $x$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution

Therefore even if $X$ is a continuous random variable, $X|X = x$ is also just like a constant. As it is a discrete random variable, so it has the probability mass function but not pdf.

For the next one, I guess you are talking about the conditional pdf again. This time the $x$ cannot be missed out. The result is similar to the conditional pdf $f_{e|X=x}(e|x)$ but also shifted by $x$, i.e.
$$ f_{X+e|X=x}(e|x) = f_{e|X=x}(e-x|x) $$